# Google Charts LogScale not working

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to make a bar graph and I'm trying to get the graph to use a logscale on the vertical axis but it's not working for some reason. I've tried using logScale and scaleType but neither of them work.

Here's my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Vendor', 'Nootropics Depot', 'Pure Nootropics', 'Peak Nootropics', 'Absorb Health'],
    ['ALCAR', 0.07, 0.20, 0.12, 0.24],
    ['Agmatine', 0.13, null, 0.23, null],
    ['Coluracetam', 13.80, 27.49, null, null],
    ['Oxiracetam', 0.47, 0.37, 0.58, 0.63],
    ['Phenibut', 0.22, null, 0.59, 0.60],
    ['Phenylpiracetam', 2.83, 3.33, 5.30, null],
    ['Polygala', 0.42, null, null, null],
    ['Pramiracetam', 1.67, 2.22, 1.60, 2.60],
    ['PRL-8-53', 23.99, null, null, null],
    ['Rhodiola Rosea 3% Rosavins', 0.23, 0.60, 0.32, 0.26],
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: 'tablets',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true
  });
  formatter.format(data, 0);
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '$',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  formatter.format(data, 2);
  formatter.format(data, 3);
  formatter.format(data, 4);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Cheapest price per gram',
    },
    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    hAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Price',
      format: '$#',
      minValue: 0.1,
      logScale: true,
    },
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

}
```

JSFiddle page: https://jsfiddle.net/rm8vr1p8/

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I've even tried changing the values of the vertical axis but it just isn't working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

there are several options that are not supported by *Material* charts, including...
`{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.logScale`

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

*Material* = `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Classic* = `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

---

there is an option for *Classic* charts to look **similar** to *Material*...
`theme: 'material`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Vendor', 'Nootropics Depot', 'Pure Nootropics', 'Peak Nootropics', 'Absorb Health'],
    ['ALCAR', 0.07, 0.20, 0.12, 0.24],
    ['Agmatine', 0.13, null, 0.23, null],
    ['Coluracetam', 13.80, 27.49, null, null],
    ['Oxiracetam', 0.47, 0.37, 0.58, 0.63],
    ['Phenibut', 0.22, null, 0.59, 0.60],
    ['Phenylpiracetam', 2.83, 3.33, 5.30, null],
    ['Polygala', 0.42, null, null, null],
    ['Pramiracetam', 1.67, 2.22, 1.60, 2.60],
    ['PRL-8-53', 23.99, null, null, null],
    ['Rhodiola Rosea 3% Rosavins', 0.23, 0.60, 0.32, 0.26],
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: 'tablets',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true
  });
  formatter.format(data, 0);
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '$',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  formatter.format(data, 2);
  formatter.format(data, 3);
  formatter.format(data, 4);

  var options = {
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Cheapest price per gram',
    hAxis: {
      format: 'decimal'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Price',
      format: '$#',
      minValue: 0.1,
      logScale: true
    },
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Yeah, I found out there are options that don't work with the material chart, weird. But, the upside down bar just doesn't look all that good tbh and I think it might be confusing to some readers. Is there a way to make the extreme values still stand out while simultaneously making sure the small values are still clearly distinct?